# SwiftUI Image in ZStack not aligning to bottom of screen

Tags: swift, swiftui

I have this code

```
struct ContentView: View {
    var body: some View {
        ZStack(alignment:.bottom) {
            Image("login-devices-mobile")
                .resizable()
                .scaledToFit()
            
        }.padding(0.0).background(Image("login-background").aspectRatio(contentMode: ContentMode.fill))
    }
}
```

which I am trying to display an image on the bottom of the screen. However when I run the preview. It still shows in the middle.

[image: Preview]

Any tips on anything I can do differently to align the image on the bottom of the screen?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I assume you wanted this

```
ZStack(alignment:.bottom) {
    Image("login-devices-mobile")
        .resizable()
        .scaledToFit()
    
}
.frame(maxWidth: .infinity, maxHeight: .infinity, alignment: .bottom) // << here !!
.background(Image("login-background").aspectRatio(contentMode: ContentMode.fill))
```

Comment: Thanks, this worked. Question, what's the point of the frame? Based on the UI it looks like the ZStack already has the full size of the phone. I guess it actually doesn't unless specified?

Comment: all stacks, including ZStack, by default fit to content. The frame gives size of container and common alignment inside container, alignment argument in stack init specifies how subviews aligned to each other.

Answer (score 0):

You can do something as -

```
struct ContentView: View {
var body: some View {
    ZStack() {
        Spacer() // Add these....
        Image("login-devices-mobile")
            .resizable()
            .scaledToFit()
        
    }.padding(0.0).background(Image("login-background").aspectRatio(contentMode: ContentMode.fill))
}
```

}

Hope it helped.

Answer (score 0):

Wrapping the image in a VStack should do the trick:

```
struct ContentView: View {
    var body: some View {
        ZStack() {
            VStack {
                Spacer() 
                Image("login-devices-mobile")
                    .resizable()
                    .scaledToFit()
            }
        }.padding(0.0).background(Image("login-background").aspectRatio(contentMode: ContentMode.fill))
        
    }
}
```